# Custom icon in Android toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm trying to use define a custom icon in the support Toolbar but the only icon shown is a left arrow... I tried to set it in the layout and programmatically but the result is the same.

Here is my Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

And my toolbar layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_action_bar"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/action_bar_size"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    />
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just tried it myself and the issue seems to be that you have to call `setNavigationIcon` after `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`. Otherwise it'll only show the arrow as you've described.
So to fix this issue just change the code like this:

```
//...
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
toolbar.setTitle("");
```

**Note:** Same goes for setting the title, contentDescription etc. I don't know if this a bug or if it is intended, but it's definitely kinda strange.

Comment: I have experienced the same behavior.

Comment: Rather than `toolbar.setTitle("");`, I prefer to use `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`. I think its a lot cleaner.

Comment: I have a question .. if you replace .. can you do transition in R.drawable.ic_launcher? I think that transition 'll break

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to **change menu icon**. (maybe somebody will need it)

1. In your activity

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_info, menu);
       return true;
   }
   ```
2. in your menu folder in res. (menu_info.xml)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
       <item
           android:id="@+id/menu_info_action"
           android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_icon"
           android:title="@string/information"
           app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
   </menu>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The current most efficient way to achieve this:

first display the left hand side icon correctly, call this function in onCreateView or onCreate:

```
protected void enableDisplayHomeAsHome(boolean active) {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(active); // switch on the left hand icon
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_home); // replace with your custom icon
    }
}
```

Now you can intercept this button press in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: {  //index returned when home button pressed
            homeButtonPressed();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(...);
```

This one works for me.