# Navigation Drawer Notification Icon without Actionbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

In my application I do not want to use the `actionbar` or `toolbar` as my app is fairly simplistic and having one of those two would clutter my application. I know when using an `actionbar` with a `navigation drawer` there is an icon on the top left to show the drawer exists; however, I want a small notification icon in the middle of the screen to show that the drawer exists. Perhaps a clear arrow? Is this possible? I can not find any documentation on how I would approach doing this. Thank you.

Edit:
I do not want to use ANY type of action bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**
You can wrap your indicator in a `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    <MyIndicator 
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <OtherView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update**

Use `FloatingActionButton` from design library.

---

If you use a toolbar you can set a custom icon. Here is another post doing something like that: [Custom icon in Android toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449082/custom-icon-in-android-toolbar)

Comment: The problem with this is that I do not want to use any actionbar at all. I want to place an icon at the center left of my screen where the navigation drawer comes from far away from the location of where an actionbar would be.

Comment: If it is something that will appear above all other views an be there all the time, you may want to look at anchoring a view, something like the Floating Action Bar (does not move, is above everything else). http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: a FAB is too complicated for what I want. All I want is a small icon at the center/left that allows a user to see that a navigation drawer is present and can be interacted with but without using the one on the action bar as I do not want an action bar at all.

Comment: @orrett3 I think I will go with the FAB idea. I did not understand what you meant at first but now I think this is the way to go. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom action bar in your app that can be customized according to your need.

Refer this link [Custom Action Bar](http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android)